# Sluggish Cupertino input fields when used in Forms due to state.didChange() calls

Tags: dart, flutter

UI stutters whenever CupertinoDatePicker is rotated due to using the picker in a FormField and calling `formFieldState.didChange()` on the picker's `onDateTimeChanged`

I'm trying to use Cupertino input fields in my app. 
I've followed the steps in the Flutter Gallery to use `CupertinoDatePicker`. However, I'm wrapping the input fields inside a `Form` for validation.

This works, as I was able to tie the state of the picker to the `FormFieldState`. However, UI performance is abysmal. Every time the picker is rotated, I experience stutters. This is due to continuous call of `state.didChange()` on `onDateTimeChanged`

I tried calling `state.didChange()` only after the modal popup was dismissed, and it got rid of the stutters. But I want the state of the FormField to update as the user spins the picker.

Here's my code snippet.

```
  Widget _getCupertinoDateTimeFormField(FormFieldState<DateTime> state) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        await showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
            context: state.context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return _buildBottomPicker(
                  CupertinoDatePicker(
                    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
                    initialDateTime: state.value?? DateTime.now(),
                    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                      state.didChange(newDateTime);
                    },
                  )
              );
            },

        );
      },
      child: cupertinoDecoration(state, description,
        Text(
          _formatUI(state.value),
          style: const TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.inactiveGray),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBottomPicker(Widget picker) {
    return Container(
      height: _kPickerSheetHeight,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
      color: CupertinoColors.white,
      child: DefaultTextStyle(
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: CupertinoColors.black,
          fontSize: 22.0,
        ),
        child: GestureDetector(
          // Blocks taps from propagating to the modal sheet and popping.
          onTap: () {},
          child: SafeArea(
            top: false,
            child: picker,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Widget cupertinoDecoration <T> (FormFieldState<T> state, String description, Widget field) {
  bool isError = state.errorText != null;
  Widget label = Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0),
    child: Text(
      description,
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14.0,
        color: CupertinoColors.black,
      ),
    ),
  );

  List<Widget> fieldWidgets = [label, field];
  if (isError) {
    // add our error message
    fieldWidgets.add(Text(
      state.errorText,
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      style: const TextStyle(
        color: CupertinoColors.destructiveRed,
        fontSize: 12.0,
      ),
    ));
  }

  return Container(
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: CupertinoColors.white,
      border: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(
            color: CupertinoColors.inactiveGray, width: 0.0),
      ),
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding:
      const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        bottom: false,
        child: DefaultTextStyle(
          style: const TextStyle(
            letterSpacing: -0.24,
            fontSize: 17.0,
            color: CupertinoColors.black,
          ),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: fieldWidgets,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Am I out of luck here? Are we not supposed to link the state of the picker to the state of the FormField?

Thanks in advance!